# shared library -- .so

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

In windows GUI programming we use to have dll from where we can import the symbols of dll once it is loaded.

Now i am trying my hand with .So linux shared library.
We can access shared library functions easily as mentioned in this link.
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html

Suppose i want to read & write USART for serial communication using routines written in shared library.

1. How will my shared library access -- USART driver system call interfaces  -- if driver is stically linked to kernel?
2. If driver is loded using Modprobe or insmode then --- how can shared library access the USART driver?
   Do driver have to export symbols in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shared library is to be used by *user-space* application, while the driver lives in the kernel. You don't link user-space apps directly with kernel symbols, but request kernel services via *system calls*, which are well defined and numbered for a given kernel build. Take a look [here](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html) for an overview.

Comment: but what if ... I want driver of the device to be loaded at runtime...
then how will my shared library will access system call ... as it does not know the node where device is in the /dev directory ?

Please suggest.